# Ruby on Rails with Faye, how to broadcast data to specific subcsriber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, websocket, publish-subscribe

i want to build a Ruby on Rails web-apps where using facebook style notification, for the push server i'm using FAYE, is there any solution to broadcast notification for specific client, for case studies in Facebook only your account have notification if somebody send you a message or tag your photo. Thanks

Comment: might wanna take a look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: i think in that screencast, the data is broadcast to all subscriber.

Comment: Do you want to use node.js or RoR ? There two rather seperate ways of doing it.

Comment: i'm using RoR and faye running on Thin server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your client side JavaScript, subscribe to a channel name based on the user (e.g. '/messages/userid_1234') and use that to send private messages from the server.

For security reasons, don't use the actual user ID or even a hash of the username or email, since someone could spoof a subscribe that way. Generate a random GUID on signup for each user and store that with your user's account details.